# What does "#define assert(exp) ((void) 0)" do?

Tags: c, assert

I came across this preprocessor definition while reading the source code in [**Windows Research Kernel (WRK)**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/windowsacademic/researchkernelkit.mspx) 1.2:

```
#define assert(exp) ((void) 0)
```

What does this code do? Why is it defined?

Comment: Just curious -- what's WRK 1.2?

Comment: My guess: Windows Research Kernel 1.2

Comment: Yes,it's Windows Research Kernel 1.2

Comment: John, Ben & Tony: I have edited the question to read Windows Research Kernel.

Answer (score 16):

It defines the expression assert(*anything*) to do nothing.

Presumably, the environment being used does not support the ANSI C [assert](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.1.html) statement, or the programmer was unaware of the fact that it could be disabled by defining NDEBUG.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on what **bdonlan** says, the reason the macro does not expand empty is because if it did, then something like:

```
assert(something) // oops, missed the semi-colon
assert(another_thing);
```

would compile in release mode but not in debug mode. The reason it is `((void) 0)` rather than just `0` is to prevent "statement with no effect" warnings (or whatever MSVC calls them).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, this is the definition of *assert* in *newlib* too, when `NDEBUG` is defined as a preprocessor directive. [**Newlib**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newlib) is the open source C library that is used on [**Cygwin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and embedded systems.

From the *assert* manual in *newlib*:

> The macro is defined to permit you to turn off all uses of *assert* at
>   compile time by defining `NDEBUG` as a preprocessor variable. If you do this,
>   the *assert* macro expands to **`(void(0))`**