# How to disable macro function?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

Is it OK to set debugging macros to empty string when I want to disable debug checks?
Both `assert` and `BOOST_ASSERT` are set to `((void)0)` when `NDEBUG` is defined.

Why not to do something line this?

```
#ifdef NDEBUG

#define MY_DEBUG_MACRO_FUNCTION(x,y,z) ""

#elif
  // define macros
#endif
```

Comment: Why would you prefer defining it to an empty string literal?

Comment: How do you use this debug macro? Can you show us a line where it's used?

Comment: The empty expansion and the `""` expansion both suffer from the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886013/what-does-define-assertexp-void-0-do/887446#887446).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is for the macro to *do nothing* on release builds. You could define it to an empty string literal, since `"";` is a valid expression. I would believe the reason of being defined to `((void)0)` is so that the implementation does not emmit warnings for the expression. I have no solid grounds to say this, but some minimal testing shows that `"";` generates a warning while `((void)0)` doesn't. Of course, warnings are not standarized so there could be a particular implementation that does emit a warning for `((void)0)` as well, but it would have to define `assert` to something else that doesn't on `NDEBUG` builds or it would be quite annoying to the user.

Comment: Another reason to use `((void)0)` is if the macro should act like a function call - that is, if `MACRO(), something_else()` is valid in debug mode, it shouldn't unexpectedly break in release mode.

Answer (score 2):

Not it's not ok. But you can make the "body" of the macro empty:

```
#define MY_DEBUG_MACRO_FUNCTION(x,y,z)
```

Note that there is nothing being defined, so when used nothing will be put in the source.

Comment: This has essentially the same effect as `((void)0)` - I can't think of any situation where the two would produce a different result.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Eh what? The preprocessor is basically a just a program that runs before the compiler, doing a search-replace of defined macros. Making a define empty replaces the macro with nothing. It all depends on how the macro is used of course, which the person asking the question doesn't explain.

Comment: And after replacements, I can't imagine any place where `#define MACRO()` would be valid while `#define MACRO() ((void)0)` wouldn't, or vice versa: they both serve the purpose of "statement with no result." (Though now that I think about it, `MACRO(), something_else()` might be a problem for `#define MACRO()` but would still compile as expected for `#define MACRO() ((void)0)` so I guess there is a difference.)

Answer (score 0):

Going by your subject line use #undef. This is useful when there is a macro version and a C version of the function. This way you can use the compiled code over the in-lined expanded macro.

Comment: Of course it will - udef it not a C99 processor macro - what else would you expect?

Comment: Oh look - from the C99 standard which I doubt you read! 6.10.3.5 Scope of macro definitions
1 A macro definition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding #undef
directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) until the end of the preprocessing
translation unit. Macro definitions have no significance after translation phase 4.

Comment: If you undef a macro you need to edit it out from the source code. Read assert.h if you haven't done it yet.  P.S. PPL with passing knowledge of C programming shouldn't post answers.

Comment: Can you point me to the paragraph in the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 international C language standard that says this? You obviously know a lot more about C than I do

Comment: I really hope that in the 7 years that have passed you've become far less flagrant